# What are the requirements for "expand field" in Pocket League Story?

Tags: android, pocket-league-story

Although I'm in the 6th year and have expanded almost everything, I can't expand my field to allow more facilities.

Is there a special requirement I forgot?

Answer (score 2):

Winning "Regional Cup" can unlock "Expend Field".

Comment: can? Could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official guide](http://kairospot.net/pocket-league-story-guide/) on Kairospot's website, the only requirement for the Expand Field upgrade is winning the Regional Cup. Click the Facilities tab and then Stadium Upgrades to see the requirements for all stadium upgrades.